# SOAP/SSL/Python: do_open raise urllib2.URLError SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file:system error

Tags: python-2.7, ssl, certificate, urllib2, suds

I am trying to use SOAP and a WSDL file to create a secure SSL HTTP network connection and call a login request. I am receiving a do_open error from urllib2 and I am unsure why. Please help!

Error as follows (from running SOAPconnect.py file below):

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\connectSOAP.py", line 28, in <module>
    response = client.service.login(loginInputParms)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 542, in __call__
    return client.invoke(args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 602, in invoke
    result = self.send(soapenv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 637, in send
    reply = transport.send(request)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\transport\http.py", line 77, in send
    fp = self.u2open(u2request)
  File "C:\Python27\transport.py", line 42, in u2open
    return url.open(u2request, timeout=tm)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 391, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 409, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\transport.py", line 15, in https_open
    return self.do_open(self.getConnection, req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1148, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 336265218] _ssl.c:347: error:140B0002:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file:system lib>
```

Code as follows...

```
    self.key = key
    self.cert = cert

def https_open(self, req):
    #Rather than pass in a reference to a connection class, we pass in
    # a reference to a function which, for all intents and purposes,
    # will behave as a constructor
    return self.do_open(self.getConnection, req)

def getConnection(self, host, timeout=300):
    return httplib.HTTPSConnection(host,
                                  key_file=self.key,
                                  cert_file=self.cert)
```

class HTTPSClientCertTransport(HttpTransport):

```
def __init__(self, key, cert, *args, **kwargs):
    HttpTransport.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    self.key = key
    self.cert = cert

def u2open(self, u2request):
    """
    Open a connection.
    @param u2request: A urllib2 request.
    @type u2request: urllib2.Requet.
    @return: The opened file-like urllib2 object.
    @rtype: fp
    """
    tm = self.options.timeout
    url = urllib2.build_opener(HTTPSClientAuthHandler(self.key, self.cert))
    if self.u2ver() < 2.6:
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(tm)
        return url.open(u2request)
    else:
        return url.open(u2request, timeout=tm)
```

Code to call request:

```
import transport
import cookielib
import urllib
import urllib2
from suds.client import Client

url = 'file:///C:/Python27/HPNA/api.wsdl.axis2'
pem = 'file:///C:/Python27/myappnopass.pem'
cert = 'file:///C:/Python27/myapp.crt'


client = Client(url, transport=transport.HTTPSClientCertTransport(pem, cert))
print client

loginInputParms = {
    "username": "usrnamehere",
    "password": "pwdhere"
}

response = client.service.login(loginInputParms)
```